# How can one paste bookmark references or fields as plain text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, field-codes, paste

I have a Word document with fields wherein text is generated by other parts of the document. I would like to be able to paste some parts of that document as text, so that the fields don't display the "Reference source not found" error in the new document.

Answer (score 0):

So, paste as plain text and the field structure will be removed.

If the reference is already wrong, unlink the field and then copy and paste. Unlinking the field gives simply the text, as formatted if any formatting is applied.